# VLOOKUP with Alphanumeric codes Failing even though they are equal

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vlookup, alphanumeric

What I'm trying to do is use VLOOKUP to search through for an Alphanumeric serial number in a range of data in another sheet. However, it does not seem to be recognizing that there is a match when I know for a fact that there is and that they are formatted exactly the same.

The values I'm working with look like this: FTX1724R3W2

I've ran a =A1=B2 function and it returns TRUE. 
I've copied and pasted one to the other to make sure that the formatting is the same, yet it still returns a #N/A. 
Using MATCH returns a FALSE as well.

I'm not sure what's going on, do I need to specially format the Alphanumeric codes so that they are "searchable"?

Here is the VLOOKUP that I was using...

```
=VLOOKUP(L2498, Inventory_List!$A$1:$D$2176, 1, FALSE)
```

My final goal is that it finds it in the other sheet and returns the value in the first indexed column, which is the name of the inventory object.

Comment: `VLOOKUP()` searches the first column of the indicated range, so you're looking  for the serial number in the range you want to return.

Comment: Wow, I did not know that. Thanks! That should solve my problem. If you want to add it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VLOOKUP() searches the first column of the indicated range. For the function to be effective, have the serial number column be the leftmost column of your search range.

From Microsoft:

> VLOOKUP(lookup_value,table_array,col_index_num,range_lookup)
>
> Lookup_value    The value to search in the first column of the table
>   array. Lookup_value can be a value or a reference. If lookup_value is
>   smaller than the smallest value in the first column of table_array,
>   VLOOKUP returns the #N/A error value.
>
> Table_array    Two or more columns of data. Use a reference to a range
>   or a range name. The values in the first column of table_array are the
>   values searched by lookup_value. These values can be text, numbers, or
>   logical values. Uppercase and lowercase text are equivalent.
>
> Col_index_num    The column number in table_array from which the
>   matching value must be returned. A col_index_num of 1 returns the
>   value in the first column in table_array; a col_index_num of 2 returns
>   the value in the second column in table_array, and so on.